# Android: open the selected picture in a gallery with HorizontalScrollview

Tags: android, click, imageview, gallery, horizontalscrollview

I have a gallery created with a horizontalScrollview. And I do not know how can I click in a imageview gallery, it opens in a new activity with the selected image in other gallery. this is my code:

**Main.class**

```
    float ancho = 0, alto = 0;

    LinearLayout galeria = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.galeria);

    try {
        final String[] listaImagenes = getAssets().list(directorioImagenes);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int anchoPantalla = metrics.widthPixels;

        if (listaImagenes.length > 0) {

            for (String nombreImagen : listaImagenes) {

                InputStream is = getAssets().open(directorioImagenes + "/" + nombreImagen);
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                alto = bitmap.getHeight();
                ancho = bitmap.getWidth();

                final float calculo = ancho / (alto / ALTO_IMAGEN);

                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        anchoPantalla, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(colorResources);

                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(DetalleMonumento.this, AbrirImagen.class);;
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                galeria.addView(imageView);
            }

            ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
            iv2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    anchoPantalla, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
```

**main.xml**

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fondoGaleria"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/galeria"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/estandar"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="2dp" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for (final String nombreImagen : listaImagenes) {//make nombreImagen final

                InputStream is = getAssets().open(directorioImagenes + "/" + nombreImagen);
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                alto = bitmap.getHeight();
                ancho = bitmap.getWidth();

                final float calculo = ancho / (alto / ALTO_IMAGEN);

                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        anchoPantalla, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(colorResources);

                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(DetalleMonumento.this, AbrirImagen.class);
                        i.putExtra("selectedImage",nombreImagen );//Put extra
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                galeria.addView(imageView);
            }
```

And in `onCreate` of `AbrirImagen` get this string:

```
String nombreImagen=getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedImage",null);
InputStream is = getAssets().open(directorioImagenes + "/" + nombreImagen);
```

Comment: and if when you click on the selected image is painted in another gallery and not in a imageview? As I can select in the second gallery the first selected image?